# gcloud command with timeout option

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, gcloud, scp

Is it possible to set max_timeout for gcloud commands. Incase If I want to use gcloud ssh or scp in automation, to login to multiple servers. whole process getting stucked because of some instances getting longer time. Anyway to exit the gcloud command if it reached the max_timeout?

Answer (score 2):

[`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference) has no global and [`gcloud compute ssh`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) no specific timeout settings.

`gcloud compute ssh` (and `scp`) are wrappers around the host's `ssh` and `scp` commands.

Configuration options for `ssh` are summarized in [`ssh_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) man page e.g. `-o ConnectTimeout=...`.

You can set this using `gcloud`'s (!) `--ssh-flag` flag e.g.

```
gcloud compute ssh ... --ssh-flag="-o ConnectTimeout=5"
```